# Keras model.fit returns NoneType object

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, dataset

I'm working with heavy dataset of pictures (1920x1088), that's why I've decided to load it with `tf.keras.utils.Sequence()`
This is how it looks like:

```
class Pictures(keras.utils.Sequence):
    
    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size
      
    def load_sample(self, file):
        image = Image.open(file)    # Открываем изображение
        image.load()    # Загружаем его
        return image
  
    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]
        
        return np.array([cv2.resize(cv2.imread(file_name), (1920, 1088)) for file_name in batch_x]).astype('float32') / 255.0, np.array([cv2.resize(cv2.imread(file_name), (1920, 1088)) for file_name in batch_y]).astype('float32') / 255.0
```

My model looks like:

```
model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001), loss = 'mean_absolute_error',
              metrics = ['acc'])
model.fit(Pictures(high_q, low_q, 1), epochs = 7)
```

`high_q` and `low_q` are lists of paths to the pictures

I keep getting an error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

The code works fine without `tf.keras.utils.Sequence()`, but I need to keep it

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I was asked to do it on Keras, if I could, I would rather do it with Torch

I tried different files, different formats etc.
It works if I'll delete the class, but I need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you specify the parameter x of the fit method: `model.fit(x = Pictures(high_q, low_q, 1), epochs = 7)`